# Die Polizei folgt dem Täter: why is Täter in the dative case?

Tags: grammatical-case

In the sentence "Die Polizei folgt dem Täter,"  it seems like Täter should be in the accusative case since it seems to be receiving the action of the verb "folgt." Why is it instead in the dative case?
This sentence is taken directly from Lingvist.

Comment: Because in German, as in Latin, as in most other languages that have declensions, the case is usually not specified by the logical meaning of the text but by what the previous verb requires as a case. "Receiving the action" doesn't really mean anything: after all, everything in a sentence, by definition, receives the action of the verb (otherwise it wouldn't be part of that sentence in the first place).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Identifying the "direct object" that seems to receive the action of the verb  is not a 100% reliable criterion (in German) to evaluate whether your object has to be in accusative.

You can try to use that rule in conversation (then somebody will correct you if the case is wrong), but if you write, the best you can do is to learn it by heart. Go to a dictionary, and you will find the case to the verb, usually in the form `verb + jemanden/etwas+Akk` for accusative, `verb + jemandem/etwas+Dative`.

Comment: It's not that bad a rule, though. It's very helpful, actually, as it holds true most of the time. While you are right that the receiving actant does not *necessarily* have to be in accusative case, that pretty much *is* the default (since the most common valence patterns with case complements include an acc complement (Kakk) and Kakk almost always encodes the least active actant). Obviously it is still important to be aware that some verbs have other patterns (see https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/progr@mm/6011), but it seems advantageous for learners to start from the common case.

Answer (score 6):

The verbs verfolgen (to chase) and folgen (follow) come with different cases:

For „verfolgen“ you ask „wen verfolge ich“ —> akkusativ.

Your example would be:

> die Polizei verfolgte DEN Täter

For folgen the question is: „wem folge ich“ —> dativ.

> die Polizei folgte DEM Täter

Comment: How do non-native speakers know which question to ask? (Determining the case using a question works only for native speakers who forgot some grammar or children who learn grammar. *We* on the other hand, don't know whether to ask *wen verfolge ich* or *wem verfolge ich* and your answer becomes a truism)

Comment: @c.p. You learn it by heart, just like native speakers. The question just gives you a second chance to remember the right case, which is sometimes all that is needed for our brain.

Comment: You are of course right. The problem is: There is no rule... every verb comes with specific cases, and as Graipher said: You need to learn them together with the verbs...

Comment: @Graipher For the question to work the situation should be `Knowing German + learn grammar`, while what one wants as learner is preciesly `Learn German + knowing grammar`. It's entirely the opposite situtation.

Comment: @c.p. I agree that that is the case for a learner. But this site is not only for beginner German learners AFAIK, so having an answer with a native perspective is also nice IMO. In the end this answer boils down to "It is defined this way [=you have to learn it by heart]. Answering these questions might help you remember the right answer." The other answer is probably more helpful for a learner (it is at least more explicit), so it has deservedly been accepted.

Comment: in many cases we use prepositions much like in english - and those prepositions demand a certain grammatical case (coincidentally - and most unfortunate - a few call for Genitiv, some prepositions call for Dativ, some for Akkusativ - and some depending on situation can be used with both Dativ and Akkusativ ...) so indeed learning by example is the only thing that helps

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that the rule is actually pretty reliable.

Even in this case, it holds that `verfolgen` is in accusative, since it receives the action of the verb, as you said.

However, the word `folgen` can have a slightly different meaning: Let's say you're invited, your host shows you the way to the living room and you follow him or her. So that's a thing you kind of do together. In this case you would use `folgen`. `verfolgen` implies that the object of the sentence is not supposed to know or doesn't want that you follow it (unless it wants to trick the follower or the like). So here, the subject of the sentence rather enforces sth. on the object.

Comment: "Verfolgen" can also be used if the object knows very well that you follow it.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I changed my answer.